# What is in the temp file in the root directory in CentOS?

Tags: centos

What is in the temp file in the root directory in CentOS? I want to know what content is in the temp file.

Comment: do you mean the temp directory?

Comment: No, there is one temp file in root directory of CentOS7.

Comment: that is not standard as far as I am aware, what is the file name? contents?

Comment: if you can access the terminal, you can use `cat filename` to view the file contents in the terminal

Comment: I can, but the content is garbled, I can not understand the content.  In fact, I want to create a directory in root directory to perserve the deleted files by rm command. If the files is stored tmp, it will be deleted forever when shutdowning or reboot. The directory is planned to be named temp, but there is often one file whose name is temp in root directory. I am just curious about it.

Comment: honestly never stumbled upon a *temp* file in a root dir (not much of cent user but still...) user and group? permissions? maybe that can give a clue as to what it is. If it is an azure vm maybe it is some azure file?

Comment: I can't make sure that the temp file is temp junk file from the CentOS operating system or is the temporary file generated by the installed software.

Comment: just googled to see if the issue has popped up before, found an identical issue! clicked it! it was this question -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard file or part of the distribution, it was probably created by some process, perhaps an installation or execution of an application.

To check if the file is in use, you can use the command:

```
> lsof /temp
```

Eg

```
# lsof /dev/null
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd 1 root 0u CHR 1.3 0t0 5460 /dev/null
systemd 1 root 1u CHR 1.3 0t0 5460 /dev/null
....
```

Then to get information on when modified, the owner, etc., you can use the command:

```
> stat /temp
```

Eg

```
# stat /dev/null
  File: ‘/dev/null’
  Size: 0 Blocks: 0 IO Block: 4096 character special file
Device: 5h/5d Inode: 5460 Links: 1 Device type: 1,3
Access: (0666/crw-rw-rw-) Uid: (0/root) Gid: (0/root)
Context: system_u: object_r: null_device_t: s0
Access: 2019-12-19 12: 47: 58.934687497 +0000
Modify: 2019-12-19 12: 47: 58.934687497 +0000
Change: 2019-12-19 12: 47: 58.934687497 +0000
 Birth: -
```

To know the type of file you can execute the command:

```
> file /temp
```

Eg

```
# file /usr/bin/gzip
/usr/bin/ gzip: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID [sha1] = 526d77ff7164870f948d8f97aaf0a888cc561b30, stripped
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/tmp` directory contains mostly files that are required temporarily ( Place where you can put files for a temporary time. )it is used by different programs to create lock files (Like DB – mysql - use this folder to create locks for the databases when a transaction is going on) and for temporary storage of data.

Many of those files are important for currently running programs and deleting them may end in a system crash.
The Linux OS itself uses this folder for putting temporary files.
For Ex – unzip a file, the contents are first extracted to /tmp and are then moved to the location extract the files.

The contents of the `/tmp` folder are automatically removed on reboot in most of Debian OS.

RedHat/CentOS/Federa clears the `/tmp` folder if the files are not accessed for 10 days. Ubuntu clears it on boot.

More info Please [refer](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html)

Comment: the questionee means a file

Comment: /tmp dir. exist ?

Comment: see comments on the question

Comment: @ming-li  can you paste some contents of temp file ? it stores temp information only

Comment: I did not ask the question, take a look at the comments under the question itself